# Eclipse slidingmenu error?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, slidingmenu

I have some pretty unique errors in Eclipse. So here's what's happening:
In my Android app (in Eclipse) I have all of these slidingmenu errors and other related Errors.  I cannot figure out how to fix these errors because I am a complete nube. Heres my code:

```
package ws.stefma.nguide;


import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Activity_Start<SlidingMenu> extends Activity {

SlidingMenu slidingMenu;

boolean check = true;

Menu menu;

public static ArrayList<String> chapterContentList = new ArrayList<String>();

/*
 * IMPORTANT
 * INSERT HERE YOUR CHAMPTERS NAME
 * THESE NAMES ARE SHOING ON THE LEFT SITE OF THE APP
 * IN THE SLIDINGMENU!!
 * 
 * USE THIS NAMES IN YOUR STRINGS.XML TOO!!
 */
ArrayList<String> chapterList = new ArrayList<String>() {{
    add("Linux");
    add("Android");
    add("Debian");
}};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width = size.x;

    slidingMenu = new SlidingMenu(this);
    slidingMenu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
    slidingMenu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    slidingMenu.setShadowWidth(5);
    slidingMenu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    slidingMenu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
    slidingMenu.setBehindWidth(width-width/3);
    slidingMenu.setFadeEnabled(true);
    slidingMenu.setMenu(R.layout.slidingmenu);

    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);

    ListAdapter listenAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, chapterList);
    lv.setAdapter(listenAdapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView av, View v, int i, long l) {
            switch(i) {
            case 0:
                new Task_SplitText(Activity_Start.this, chapterList.get(i), menu).execute();
                slidingMenu.showContent();
                check = true;
                break;
            case 1:
                new Task_SplitText(Activity_Start.this, chapterList.get(i), menu).execute();
                slidingMenu.showContent();
                check = true;
                break;
            case 2:
                new Task_SplitText(Activity_Start.this, chapterList.get(i), menu).execute();
                slidingMenu.showContent();
                check = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    this.menu = menu;

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_start, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
    TextView tv = (TextView) ll.getChildAt(0);

    int q = 0;
    for(q = 0; q < chapterContentList.size(); q += 1) {
        Log.e("Liste2", chapterContentList.get(q));
        if(chapterContentList.get(q).equals(tv.getText().toString())) {
            Log.e("chapterContenList", chapterContentList.get(q));
            Log.e("tvgetText", tv.getText().toString());
            break;
        }
    }
    Log.e("hallo", String.valueOf(q));

    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            if(check) {
                slidingMenu.showMenu();
                check = false;
            } else {
                slidingMenu.showContent();
                check = true;
            }
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_previous:
            MenuItem pageItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_page);
            String[] x = pageItem.getTitle().toString().split("/");
            try {
                int page = Integer.parseInt(x[0]);
                page -= 1;
                pageItem.setTitle(page+"/"+x[1]);
            } catch(Exception exe) {
                exe.printStackTrace();
            }
            ll.removeAllViews();
            ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollview);
            sv.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);

            while(!chapterContentList.get(q).equals("END")) {
                q -= 1;
            }
            q -= 1;
            while(!chapterContentList.get(q).equals("END")) {
                q -= 1; 
                if(q == -1) {
                    break;
                }
                Log.e("q", String.valueOf(q));
            }
            q = q + 1;
            while(!chapterContentList.get(q).equals("END")) {
                if(chapterContentList.get(q).contains("IMAGENAME")) {
                    // Create ImageView

                    String imagename = chapterContentList.get(q).replaceAll("--", "").replaceAll("IMAGENAME", "");
                    ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
                    int j = getResources().getIdentifier(imagename, "drawable", getPackageName());
                    iv.setImageResource(j);

                    ll.addView(iv); 
                } else {
                    // Create TextView

                    TextView tvNew = new TextView(this);
                    tvNew.setText(chapterContentList.get(q));

                    ll.addView(tvNew);
                }   
                q += 1; 
                Log.e("q2", String.valueOf(q));
            }
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_next:
            MenuItem pageItem2 = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_page);
            String[] x2 = pageItem2.getTitle().toString().split("/");
            try {
                int page = Integer.parseInt(x2[0]);
                page += 1;
                pageItem2.setTitle(page+"/"+x2[1]);
            } catch(Exception exe) {
                exe.printStackTrace();
            }
            ll.removeAllViews();
            ScrollView sv2 = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollview);
            sv2.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);

            while(!chapterContentList.get(q).equals("END")) {
                q += 1;
            }
            q += 1;
            while(!chapterContentList.get(q).equals("END")) {
                if(chapterContentList.get(q).contains("IMAGENAME")) {
                    // Create ImageView

                    String imagename = chapterContentList.get(q).replaceAll("--", "").replaceAll("IMAGENAME", "");
                    ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
                    int j = getResources().getIdentifier(imagename, "drawable", getPackageName());
                    iv.setImageResource(j);

                    ll.addView(iv);
                } else {
                    // Create TextView

                    TextView tvNew = new TextView(this);
                    tvNew.setText(chapterContentList.get(q));

                    ll.addView(tvNew);
                }   
                q += 1; 
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return true;
    }
}
}
```

the errors are as below

```
1.Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN cannot be resolved or is not a field   Activity_Start.java /NGuide/src/ws/stefma/nguide    line 62 Java Problem

2.Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
The method showMenu() is undefined for the type SlidingMenu Activity_Start.java /NGuide/src/ws/stefma/nguide    line 126    Java Problem

3.Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
The method showContent() is undefined for the type SlidingMenu  Activity_Start.java /NGuide/src/ws/stefma/nguide    line 129    Java Problem

4.Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
LEFT cannot be resolved or is not a field   Activity_Start.java /NGuide/src/ws/stefma/nguide    line 61 Java Problem

5.Cannot instantiate the type SlidingMenu   Activity_Start.java /NGuide/src/ws/stefma/nguide    line 60 Java Problem

6.The method showContent() is undefined for the type SlidingMenu    Activity_Start.java /NGuide/src/ws/stefma/nguide    line 84 Java Problem

7.The method showContent() is undefined for the type SlidingMenu    Activity_Start.java /NGuide/src/ws/stefma/nguide    line 89 Java Problem

8.The method showContent() is undefined for the type SlidingMenu    Activity_Start.java /NGuide/src/ws/stefma/nguide    line 79 Java Problem

9.The method setFadeEnabled(boolean) is undefined for the type SlidingMenu  Activity_Start.java /NGuide/src/ws/stefma/nguide    line 67 Java Problem

10.The method setMenu(int) is undefined for the type SlidingMenu    Activity_Start.java /NGuide/src/ws/stefma/nguide    line 68 Java Problem

11.SLIDING_CONTENT cannot be resolved or is not a field Activity_Start.java /NGuide/src/ws/stefma/nguide    line 65 Java Problem

12.The method setBehindWidth(int) is undefined for the type SlidingMenu Activity_Start.java /NGuide/src/ws/stefma/nguide    line 66 Java Problem

13.The method setShadowWidth(int) is undefined for the type SlidingMenu Activity_Start.java /NGuide/src/ws/stefma/nguide    line 63 Java Problem

14.The method setFadeDegree(float) is undefined for the type SlidingMenu    Activity_Start.java /NGuide/src/ws/stefma/nguide    line 64 Java Problem
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have build-path errors. You got to resolve them first. Get the latest version (or the most appropriate version) of [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) and follow the standard way of adding it as a library and resolving dependencies if any, as shown [here](http://boroniatechnologies.com/installing-slidingmenu-android-library-and-example/).